# How do I make a plot with less data from a column in a csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, plot

I used pivot to make the column "state" into lines on the line plot.

```
df = df.pivot(index='year', columns='state', values='fatal')
```

When showing the plot, I get too many because of the amount of states in the dataframe.

This is what I get
[image: This is what i get.]

I have tried to use df.loc on the states but I can't seem to find a way to plot it afterwards.

```
df.loc[df['state'].isin(['al','ar','fl','wa'])]
```

And this is what I get when plotting the code.
[plot from df.loc list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDBSw.png)

As seen, I only want some states to appear from the column, not all of them. How could I achieve this? Many thanks!

Comment: Filter for the states u want and plot them ?

Answer (score 0):

I would filter, pivot and then plot the result in one line:

```py
toplot = df[df['state'].isin(['al','ar','fl','wa'])].pivot(index='year', columns='state', values='fatal')
```

You could also just filter the pivoted frame - the states are now the columns so just keep your first line and then filter:

```py
df = df.pivot(index='year', columns='state', values='fatal')
toplot = df[['al','ar','fl','wa']]
```